# Deploying Angular app on Azure using VS Code doesn't update the old version

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular App which is already deployed on Azure. I made some changes and tested the app locally using `ng serve` to verify my changes. Then I used `ng build` to get the artifacts in the `dist` directory. I then use the Azure App Services extension in VS code to "Deploy to Web App..." and selected the `dist` folder for deployment. It then gives me a message that it was successfully deployed. However, when I go to the website, I still see the old version and not my new version which I just deployed. Can someone please point out what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Have you refreshed your browser cache?

Comment: I tested in incognito mode. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Yeah that would also cover it, have you tried redeploying again?

Comment: I found this today, could have be related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44285953/6259188

Comment: Redeploying didn't help. Thanks I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something which worked for me:

- to build(`**ng build --prod**`) on the modified project to update the dist folder,
- Try deploying it now to the azure web app
- Finally if still doesn't reflect , check in Azure web app using KUDU to see if the latest changes are there.
- Try restarting your web app as well.

Hope it helps.